# My database won't update, something wrong with my connection string

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've been trying to figure this out for ages and I tried different methods but nothing seems to work. I have done a successful migration and now have a migrations file for my project. I am trying to update my database but it fails each time I try.

For the record I am using a Macbook and using Visual Code for the project. I typed this into the command line

```
dotnet ef database update InitialCreate
```

I have also tried this:

```
dotnet ef database update -c LoanContext Development
```

This is what shows in my command line when I enter the above

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]  

Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'LoanContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)
>
> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): Undefined error: 0
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SSRP.GetPortByInstanceName(String browserHostName, String instanceName)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNIProxy.CreateTcpHandle(DataSource details, Int64 timerExpire, Object callbackObject, Boolean parallel)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
>      at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded, TState state)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
>
> ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid)

This is my `appsettings.json` file

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
},
"AllowedHosts": "*",
"connectionStrings": {
    "DevConnection": "server=(local)\\sqlexpress;Database=LoanDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
}
```

Code in my startup.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using WebAPI.Models;

namespace WebAPI
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            services.AddDbContext<LoanContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried changing the connection string through this site https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/ . Nothing works, any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DevConnection")` output? Second silly question: Are you sure that you are running an actual SqlExpress service on the new machine?

Comment: The error is with the connection string : server=(local)\\sqlexpress;Database=LoanDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True    I usually start by opening SQL Server Management Studio.  The login window show the Server name (local) and instance (sqlexpress). You need to modify the connection string to match.  The login will show type of Credentials.  It should show windows to agree with the connection string "Trusted_Connection=True".  Then the user account that you are using will be used for authentication.  The database also have to have same privileges.

Comment: At the end of error is clearly saying that `Connection string is not valid `. make sure about your SQL server.

Comment: I solved the issue, I removed the server name to the connection string, apparently adding the server to that string doesn't work for MacBooks. Thanks for all the answers!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have TCP enabled for the SQL Server instance?

Start SQL Server Configuration Manager and expand SQL Server Network Configuration and Protocols and check the values.  The following example show TCP/IP is disabled - if so then right-click on it and set it to enabled and restart your instance.

[image]